BSOD issue on host windows 11 when switching from NAT to bridged in vbox
Been using vbox for a while after a recent update to vbox 7.0.20, switching from NAT to bridged causing the host machine (win 11) to crash and becomes BSOD.
switching back to NAT the system didn't crash. Using kali and zorin on vbox been facing the issue for both the os [BSOD Details][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/o5I9jA4i.jpg    --BSOD Details
installed guest additions on both of them, i need to switch to bridged mode for my study purpose, any help will be accepted,
cheers ;)

Hello, my very first action will be: run the command "/sfc scannow" as admin in a prompt and second action reinstall VBOX, keep in mind reinstalling VBOX doesn't mean re-create your VM if you save then, Are you sure your VBOX version is 7.0.20 and not 7.0.16 ?

@Maslie, yes i had used vbox 7.0.20 and because of this issue i downed to 7.0.18 and still is the same, i feel like the vbox doesnt read my internal network card which is of mediatek,
I done the following:
Checked whether a new update for the driver came in for the windows - and NO
Checked a diagnostic scan to know any fault happened in the services or in the the drivers the result came as NO
I done some commands in the kali on vbox suggested by chatgpt and still no progress.
i had used the bridged mode in the past, i think i messed up with some commands while i heard of chat gpt.
